# Finding index of an element in a specified array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I'm in the making of a google sheets app script where I want to check if a value from one cell is in an array of values, then find what the index is so I can direct my function to that cell.

I'm at the point where I have my array in a variable called `distArray`, and I want to check if `"id"` is in that array.

Here's the code to better visualize:

```
function logs() {
  let app = SpreadsheetApp
  let dest = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Baza Danych");
  let lastrow = dest.getLastRow();

  let destArr = dest.getRange(2, 1, lastrow).getValues();
  let id = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Zgloszenia").getRange(6, 2).getValue();
  let position = destArr.indexOf(id);

  Logger.log(id)
  Logger.log(destArr)
  Logger.log(position)
}
```

And [here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdRSc.png) I get.

My problem is that no matter what the value of `"id"` is, the index is either `-1` or `0` meaning the value either is not in the array or is in the first cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `.flat()` at the end of the line:

```
let destArr = dest.getRange(2, 1, lastrow).getValues();
```

This way:

```
let destArr = dest.getRange(2, 1, lastrow).getValues().flat();
```

**Explanation:**

The method `getValues()` gives you a 2d array `[[1],[2],[3],...]`.

The `flat()` method converts a 2d array into an ordinary flat array `[1,2,3,...]`.

After that you will able to use `array.indexOf(element)` to get an index of the element in the array.

Comment: simple, efficient!

Answer (score 1):

**Description**

Yuri's solution is a good example if you don't want to know which element of the array contains the value your looking for.  But if you need to know which row of the array contains the value the following example shows how to search a 2D array.

**Script**

```
function find() {
  try {
    let a = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f'],['g','h']];
    let b = "f";
    let c = a.findIndex( d => d.indexOf(b) >= 0 );
    console.log("c = "+c);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

7:51:23 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:51:24 AM  Info    c = 2
7:51:23 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- [Array.findIndex()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp)
- [Array.indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)